# pyqt_fit.CurveFitting example throwing error

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to use the [PyQt-Fit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt-Fit) library in my code but am running into trouble. Just for experimenting, i copied the example code from the package homepage.

Here is the code i'm running:

```
import pyqt_fit
from pyqt_fit import plot_fit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab
x = np.arange(0,3,0.01)
y = 2*x + 4*x**2 + np.random.randn(*x.shape)
def fct(params, x):
    (a0, a1, a2) = params
    return a0 + a1*x + a2*x*x
fit = pyqt_fit.CurveFitting(x, y, (0,1,0), fct)
result = plot_fit.fit_evaluation(fit, x, y)
print(fit(x)) # Display the estimated values
plot_fit.plot1d(result)
pylab.show()
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
    fit = pyqt_fit.CurveFitting(x, y, (0,1,0), fct)

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (5 given)
```

[Example code from the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/PyQt-Fit/Param_tut.html#a-simple-example) gives the same error.

I tried googling my problem, but i can't find a working example.

What do i need to change to pass all the parameters properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by looking at the PyQt-Fit 1.2 source code to see how the signature changed between versions 1.2 and 1.3. The old `CurveFitting.__init__()` looked like this:

```
def __init__(self, xdata, ydata, p0, fct, args=(), residuals=None,
             fix_params=(), Dfun=None, Dres = None, col_deriv=1,
             constraints = None, *lsq_args, **lsq_kword):
```

The [new one](http://pyqt-fit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/pyqt_fit/curve_fitting.html#CurveFitting) looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, xdata, ydata, **kwords):
    self._fct = None
    self._Dfun = None
    self._residuals = None

   # snip...

    self.xdata = xdata
    self.ydata = ydata

    for n in kwords:
        setattr(self, n, kwords[n])

# getters and setters for all the other properties
```

As can be seen, it now expects everything except for xdata and ydata to be named parameters, while previously `p0` and `fct` were unnamed. [This is conspicuously missing from the documentation.]

The function call in the example should really look like this:

```
fit = pyqt_fit.CurveFitting(x, y, p0=(0,1,0), function=fct)
```

For me at least, it still throws an error on the next line:

```
 File "untitled0.py", line 18, in <module>
    result = plot_fit.fit_evaluation(fit, x, y)

  File "pyqt_fit/plot_fit.py", line 165, in fit_evaluation
    popt = fit.popt

AttributeError: 'CurveFitting' object has no attribute 'popt'
```

It seems like it wants me to call the returned `fit()` function before trying to graph it. I just switched the order of the `print(fit(x))` line with this one, and that solved it.

The working code is now:

```
import pyqt_fit
from pyqt_fit import plot_fit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab
x = np.arange(0,3,0.01)
y = 2*x + 4*x**2 + np.random.randn(*x.shape)
def fct(params, x):
    (a0, a1, a2) = params
    return a0 + a1*x + a2*x*x
fit = pyqt_fit.CurveFitting(x, y, p0=(0,1,0), function=fct)
print(fit(x)) # Display the estimated values1
result = plot_fit.fit_evaluation(fit, x, y)
plot_fit.plot1d(result)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Self-answered because it was a real problem that i spent a while trying to solve, and wanted to put the solution out there.